# expression ((sizetype)(((ssizetype)length) + -1)) + 1

Tags: c++, gcc

```
template <int I>
struct A {};

int main()
{
    int length  = 1;
    int ar[length];
    A<sizeof(ar)> a;
    return 0;
}
```

I get error: `(unsigned int)((((unsigned int)(((int)length) + -0x000000001)) + 1u) * 4u)` is not a valid template argument for type 'int' because it is a non-constant expression

What is the sense of this expression? Why can't it be just `length * 4u`?

Comment: Are you asking the purpose of the expression, or why you receive the error?

Comment: @cdhowie I ask about the sense of expression. I know about the cause of error;

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
int length  = 1;
int ar[length];
```

This is invalid C++. GCC accepts it (when not using `-pedantic-errors`, which you *should*) but the resulting expression isn’t a valid C++ object and cannot be used in `sizeof`.

Comment: Yes, I know about it. But question is why gcc made such expression.

Comment: @eXXXXXXXXXXX It is not a constant expression because `length` is not a constant expression, making `ar`'s bound non-constant.

Comment: @plash Question is why did gcc make expression `(unsigned int)((((unsigned int)(((int)length) + -0x000000001)) + 1u) * 4u)` instead of just `length * 4u`.

Comment: @eXXXXXXXXXXX Because of ‹insert weird implementation detail›. `sizeof` is **always** evaluated at compile time, but the size of `af` is simply *not known* at compile time. So GCC cannot compute `sizeof(ar)`, but apparently they didn’t hard-code a proper error message for that. Rather, somewhere in the depths of GCC the illegal expression is encountered as a side-effect of some other check. I have no idea what actually happens in GCC internally – but is that interesting?

Comment: @Konrad Rudolph I thought that it has simple explanation. Something like overflow protection but apparently you are right.